# route spec doesn't pass but route works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rspec

When I go to localhost:3000/api/guests/1 I get my show page, but when I run the spec, it doesn't pass.

Here's my spec:

```
it 'the resource is under the correct namespace' do
  get '/api/guests/1'
  expect(response).to be_success
end
```

Here's my routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    resources :gifts, only: :show
    resources :guests, only: [:index, :show] do
      resources :gifts, only: :index
    end
    resources :parties, only: [:index, :show]
  end
end
```

Here's my RSpec failure message:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
   Couldn't find Guest with 'id'=1
```

I'm not quite sure where to look for the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not create a Guest object, so your test fails because it can't find it. Before you call `get`, you should create your Guest. Something like:

```
user = Guest.create!(:username => "jdoe")
```

And then try to get it like this:

```
get "/api/guests/#{user.id}"
```

Note! Your test database is not the same as your development database. So, most likely you have that user in dev but not in test.

Comment: OK, that works. My second spec is this though:

    it 'the show page shows correct information' do
      get '/api/guests/1'
      expect(json['name']).to eq('John Smith')
      expect(json['age']).to eq(45)
      expect(json['favorite_color']).to eq('Blue')
    end

Comment: Is there something I need to do to give rspec access to my already seeded database?

Comment: No, you should have separate DBs, and you have to prepare needed variables before each test. You should read some blogs about Rspec tests and their organization, such as this one: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-we-test-rails-applications. There all kind of ways to initialize and reuse required variable before starting your tests.

Comment: You are asking me to tell you how to do things in a wrong way, and what do you expect me to tell you? No there is no way to seed whatever DB rspec is using, and if there would be a way to do so, it would be wrong. Specs have their purpose and they relay on the data that you create for particular conditions in your tests, and some current snapshot of a database just will not do. Instead, tests in Rails have features and factories and many other things, and seeding is for your dev and production. I know, it sounds tempting to re-point databases, but it is not the way.

Comment: OK, no problem. I didn't write the specs and they're all written this way, so I'm trying to figure out if there's a way I can work around them the way they're written. If not, I don't really need to pass these specs, I just wanted to make sure I'm not missing something.

Comment: Hmmm, it is interesting. Maybe there is something which I am not aware of and your specs are set up in a way I am not familiar with. In this case, your setup is pretty specific. Check around your project and see what can you find. Try to use some specific things from your tests such as "John Smith" in your example above, grep for this within your project, and you might get a clue.

Comment: Also, if you have git, you can try to go backward with code changes using `git log -p` and look for the time those tests were written and see whether you can puzzle out from the nearby commits what that programmer was doing and how.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the solution: bundle exec rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=test --trace

I ran this line with a typo the first time. Oops!

Comment: That probably another way to create data for tests. Though, I would not recommend it. While it is faster, but it is more difficult to maintain. But for your purposes it probability does not matter.

Comment: And, it does not mean that my answer was wrong for your particular question.